# XML Descendants always return Empty result

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I don't know why I can't make this work in any case.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XML_TESTER_CM
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xDoc;
            xDoc = XDocument.Load("Palette_Sets.xml");

            var result1 = xDoc.Descendants("SETS");
            var result2 = xDoc.Descendants("PALETTE");
            var result3 = xDoc.Descendants("COLOR");
        }
    }
}
```

My XML file:
https://pastecode.xyz/view/25d53914

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<SETS>
  <PALETTE id="Default Set">
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Red</Name>
      <RGBString>#FF0000</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Blue</Name>
      <RGBString>#0000FF</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Cyan</Name>
      <RGBString>#00FFFF</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Magenta</Name>
      <RGBString>#FF00FF</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Green</Name>
      <RGBString>#00FF00</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Orange</Name>
      <RGBString>#FFAA00</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Yellow</Name>
      <RGBString>#FFFF00</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
  </PALETTE>
  <PALETTE id="OLD Set">
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Olive</Name>
      <RGBString>#7f8229</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Dark Blue</Name>
      <RGBString>#272c72</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
    <COLOR>
      <Name>Silver</Name>
      <RGBString>#9597af</RGBString>
    </COLOR>
  </PALETTE>
</SETS>
```

xDoc returns the document correctly, but Descendants method doesn't work at all each resultX var has an empty result view.

Comment: It works for me, what happens if you try `Console.WriteLine(result1.Count());` and repeat that for each result?  Specifically how are you verifying that they are empty?

Comment: I added the Console.WriteLine for all 3 result var, this is the output:
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetDescendants>d__38
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetDescendants>d__38
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetDescendants>d__38

Ok count works:
I get: 1 - 2 - 10

Comment: I really don't understand the behaviour of what happens in Visual Studio with variable inspection.
If I do write Console.WriteLine(result1); and inspect Results View it's empty.
If I do Console.WriteLine(result1.Count()); Result View it's not empty and I can see the content of the result.

I think only images can explain what's appening, maybe someone can solve this.

Comment: https://i.snag.gy/wIP8dp.jpg

At this point I think it has something to do with asyncronous access to  xDoc. But it scared me it wasn't giving me the results.

Comment: What are you **expecting** `Console.WriteLine(result1);` to output? _It definitely **works** it just isn't doing what you expect - if you tell us what you expect (be very explicit) we can help you achieve it._ It is nothing to do with asynchronous access.

Comment: I'm not interested in the Console.WriteLine(result1) method at all, I didn't use that on first instance, I was inspecting variables with the debugger and those were empty after returning from xDoc.Descendants, adding Console.WriteLine(result1) was suggested from juharr, then he edited the comment and wrote to use result1.Count() instead, and magically those result1,result2,result3 variables in the debugger inspector where showing correct results.

Comment: The problem is that the results are lazy-loaded.  So, the debugger doesn't always show what you'd expect.  Usually it gives the option to load the results though.

Comment: mjwills: It's written exactly at the end of the post... "has an empty result view". Thought that was meaningful (like in the picture I posted later), but you're right I should have specified I was working in Visual Studio and was using the debugger inspector to make it more precise.

@juharr Interesting. Can you direct me where this option to load results is found ?

Comment: It's usually beside of the name of the variable with a circular arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using Dictionaries with xml.  Below I converted your xml into colors :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);


            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, PaletteColor>> dict = doc.Descendants("PALETTE")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("id"), y => y.Elements("COLOR").Select(c => new PaletteColor() { name = (string)c.Element("Name"), color = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(((string)c.Element("RGBString")).Substring(1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)) })
                    .GroupBy(a => a.name, b => b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
    public class PaletteColor
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Color color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Here is answer using list instead of 2nd dictionary

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);


            Dictionary<string, List<PaletteColor>> dict = doc.Descendants("PALETTE")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("id"), y => y.Elements("COLOR").Select(c => new PaletteColor() { name = (string)c.Element("Name"), color = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(((string)c.Element("RGBString")).Substring(1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)) }).ToList())
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
    public class PaletteColor
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Color color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to do almost the same thing, actually a Dictionary with a Collection of Palette Color Objects. I like how you wrote the code, I will take that in consideration.
And even my test code was working (it was just the debugger inspector showing problems) I will accept your answer like the answer to the question.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your code to make a Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<PaletteColor>>, where PaletteColor is a class with 3 Properties: Name and Color, plus another Properties that has a default value of 0 and doesn't need to be in the XML.
Trying to find an elegant solution derived from yours but I don't know how to change it to make it work.

Comment: I updated code to use a class instead of anonymous object.